# AWS Cognito - Restrict Parts of Static S3 Website to Logged in Users

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I'm building a small static website that I have hosted on s3. I used Cognito to get some basic user verification up and running (login, logout). I want to restrict certain parts of the website to only logged in users.

I worked through module 2 of this workshop https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-serverless-workshops/tree/master/WebApplication. In this workshop, the page `/rides.html` is restricted to logged in users. If you are not logged in and try to access `/rides.html`, the page will start to load, and then quickly redirect you to `/signin.html`. The trouble with this is that unauthorized users can still see the rides page for a split second before redirection occurs.

Here is their code that handles redirecting a user who hasn't logged in. It is run as javascript when a user tries to access `/rides.html`

```
   WildRydes.authToken.then(function setAuthToken(token) {
       if (token) {
           authToken = token;
       } else {
           window.location.href = '/signin.html';
       }
   }).catch(function handleTokenError(error) {
       alert(error);
       window.location.href = '/signin.html';
   });
```

I am having a lot of trouble determining the best way to ensure only users who have signed in can access parts of my website. Very new to anything webdev/AWS related, and I'm having some trouble finding this information online.

**Edit: To clear up what I want to achieve - I want the entire `rides.html` page to be inaccessible to anyone who hasn't logged in.**

**Solution: We ended up putting a restricted CloudFront in front of the s3 bucket. Then, we had a lambda triggered when someone tried to access the CloudFront. Here is a tutorial: https://douglasduhaime.com/posts/s3-lambda-auth.html**

Comment: This isn’t really how S3 is meant to work. If the bucket is public read, then it’s public read. Doesn’t matter what you do, the content is not protected in any meaningful way. If you make some objects private, ie they need was auth, then you can do that but it’s not clear how that would work in the context of a real website.

Comment: I get where you are coming from. This is a small website we created to get a feel for s3, Cognito, and AWS in general. It really only consists of 2 pages - a login page, and another page that should only be accessible to someone who has logged in. Is there a way to make it work in the context of this small project?

Comment: I do not believe there is with just s3 and Cognito... I know you can use Cognito to provide for s3 object access on a per user basis... but I don’t know of any way to craft a bucket policy that would effectively restrict a bucket/object to any user in a certain Cognito user pool. You’d need a lambda or a server in front to figure that out for you.

Comment: Tbh, even if you DID manage to craft a bucket policy (might be doable)... restricting page access is not what it would be intended for and you couldnt convince the browser to set the headers required to authenticate... you’d have to request and load the content in JavaScript. The use case for such a policy would be more along the lines of restricting access to files / images instead of web pages. For a lot of reasons, it seems like if you NEED to restrict access to a certain html file, s3 and Cognito doesn’t seem the tool for the job.

Answer (score 1):

I did not work through the workshop you mention, but from reading the README of module 2 I understand that they are implementing *User Authentication and Registration with Amazon Cognito User Pools*.

Redirecting from a site which is inaccessible is fine, you must not ensure that it is never loaded. Let me explain why:

The "sensitive" information which is displayed on the site is **not static**. It is loaded from a REST backend in module 4. Since the **authentication is static** by means of JWT, the data is never loaded from the REST backend if the user is not authenticated.

So what should the page `/rides.html` do?

- if the user is authenticated (i.e. has obtained a JWT which is valid) the REST backend should be called to obtain the data
- if the user is not authenticated (i.e. no JWT present) or the JWT is present and not valid anymore the user should be redirected to the sign-in page; note that no sensible data was obtained from the REST backend before the redirect

**EDIT:**

In order to restrict access to one single object in S3, you could add a bucket policy like the following one to the s3 bucket:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<your-bucket-name>/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "NotPrincipal": {
                "AWS": "<your-user-arn>"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<your-bucket-name>/rides.html"
        }
    ]
}
```

This will make all objects public except the `rides.html` file. If you want to access it, you will have to use a signed url. [1]
Please note that you must not use a bucket or object ACL which grants public access to everyone in conjunction with this approach since it might prevent the object from staying private.

#### Another approach (for using a federated user instead of a regular IAM user)

I do not know if the following works because of limitations in the docs [2], but you could give it a try.
It might be possible to use a web identity federation provider in the *NotPrincipal* attribute: `"Federated": "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com"`.
You could then narrow down which federated user has access to the `rides.html` object via condition keys (e.g. *cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub*). [3]

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-urls.html

[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_notprincipal.html

[3] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_iam-condition-keys.html

Comment: Understood, maybe I should have been more clear in my end goals. I want the entire ```rides.html``` page to be totally inaccessible to someone who isn't logged in. I'll edit my original question to reflect this.

Comment: My bad, I should have answered your question instead of questioning your use case. Do you use AWS amplify console to host the app?

Comment: No, the app is hosted directly in the s3 bucket

Comment: I updated my answer with an approach how to block access to the file.

Comment: Thanks Martin! I will give these approaches a shot today. Going back to your original answer - why is it secure to have the rest backend call the database with sensitive information after the user is authenticated? What is preventing an unauthenticated user from changing the flow of the js file to make it call to the database without being signed in?

Comment: You are authenticating against the backend with every request you make (see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signing_aws_api_requests.html). Since the authentication is stateless, the backend is validating the signature which is passed with the request. If the signature is missing or invalid, the request is rejected. There is no persistent session between client and AWS services.

Comment: how could an unauthenticated user in your scenario call the database when the database requires authentication?